# Remove a particular push notification from notification center tray

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I need to remove a particular notification from the notification center.
In my app I am opening a particular kind notification using this method

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.getDeliveredNotifications(completionHandler: { (notificationRequests) in
        for x in notificationRequests {
        print(x.request.content.userInfo)
    }
    })
```

so I want to remove that notification after I read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every notification has an identifier and after reading a notification you can simply do -

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: [notification_identifier_here])
```